# Can't use multiple services in one controller in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use 2 services in one controller, but somehow the second service doesn't work:

First controller (which works):

```
angular.module('services', [

])
    .service('userService', function ($http, $q, auth, userFactory) {
        var user = null;

        if(!user){
            userFactory.getUser(auth.currentUser()).getValue(function(result){
                user = result;
                return result;
            });
        }

        this.getUser = function() {
            //console.log("user: ", user);
            return user;
        }

        this.setUserChallenge = function(id) {
            var newUser = user;
            //console.log("newuser: ", newUser);
            newUser.currentchallenge = id;
            //console.log("newuser2: ", newUser);
            user = newUser;
        }

    })
;
```

Second service:

```
angular.module('services', [

])
    .service('suggestionsService', function ($http, auth, challengeFactory, userService) {
        var suggestions = null;

        if(!suggestions){
            $scope.$watch(userService.getUser, function(getUser){
                console.log(getUser);
                if(getUser) {
                    challengeFactory.findManyChallengesById(getuser.challengessuggestions).getValue(function(challengesResponse) {
                        $scope.suggestions = challengesResponse.data;
                    });
                }

            });
            /*challengeFactory.getChallenges().getValue(function(result){
                suggestions = result;
                return result;
            });*/
        }

        this.getSuggestions = function() {
            return suggestions;
        }

    })
;
```

I reference them like this:

```
angular.module('eva').controller('ChallengeCtrl', ['$scope', 'auth','$translate', 'challengeFactory', 'userFactory', 'userService', 'suggestionsService'
  function($scope, auth, $translate, challengeFactory, userFactory, userService, suggestionsService ) {
```

But I get this error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=suggestionsServiceProvider%20%3C-uggestionsService%20%3C-%20ChallengeCtrl

I reference them in my index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/services/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services/ChallengesService.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services/SuggestionsService.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services/UserService.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Why is this happening, the service has the same structure as the first one but still it doesn't work.

ChallengeFactory:

```
angular.module('factories')
.factory('challengeFactory', ['$http', '$state', '$window',
  function($http, $state, $window) {
    var challengeFactory = {};

    challengeFactory.startSeries = function(user){
      return{
        getValue: function(){
          $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'http://groep6api.herokuapp.com/startuserseries',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            transformRequest: function(obj) {
              var str = [];
              for(var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
              return str.join("&");
            },
            data : {username: user}
          });
        }
      }
    };

    challengeFactory.setsuggestions = function(user, suggestions){
      return{
        getValue: function(){
          $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'http://groep6api.herokuapp.com/setsuggestions',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            transformRequest: function(obj) {
              var str = [];
              for(var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
              return str.join("&");
            },
            data : {username: user, challengessuggestions: JSON.stringify(suggestions)}
          });
        }
      }
    };

    challengeFactory.getChallenges = function(){
      return{
        getValue: function(callback){
          $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url:'http://groep6api.herokuapp.com/challenges'
          }).then(function (result) {
            callback(result.data);
          });
        }
      }
    };

    challengeFactory.findChallengeById = function(id){
      return{
        getValue: function(callback){
          $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'http://groep6api.herokuapp.com/findchallengebyid',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            transformRequest: function(obj) {
              var str = [];
              for(var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
              return str.join("&");
            },
            data : {_id: id}
          }).then(function (result) {
            callback(result);
          });
        }
      }
    };

    challengeFactory.findManyChallengesById = function(challengesIds){
      return{
        getValue: function(callback){
          $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'http://groep6api.herokuapp.com/findmanychallengesbyid',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            transformRequest: function(obj) {
              var str = [];
              for(var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
              return str.join("&");
            },
            data : {ids: JSON.stringify(challengesIds)}
          }).then(function (result) {
            callback(result);
          });
        }
      }
    }


    challengeFactory.setUserChallenge = function(user, id){
      return{
        getValue: function(callback){
          $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'http://groep6api.herokuapp.com/setuserchallenge',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            transformRequest: function(obj) {
              var str = [];
              for(var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
              return str.join("&");
            },
            data : {username: user, _id: id}
          }).then(function (result) {
            callback(result);
          });
        }
      }
    };

    challengeFactory.completeChallenge = function(user){
      return{
        getValue: function(){
          $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'http://groep6api.herokuapp.com/completecurrentchallenge',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            transformRequest: function(obj) {
              var str = [];
              for(var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
              return str.join("&");
            },
            data : {username: user}
          }).then(function (result) {

          });
        }
      }
    };

    challengeFactory.completeChallengeSeries = function(username){
      return{
        getValue: function(){
          $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'http://groep6api.herokuapp.com/completechallengeseries',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            transformRequest: function(obj) {
              var str = [];
              for(var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
              return str.join("&");
            },
            data : {username: username}
          }).then(function (result) {

          });
        }
      }
    };

    challengeFactory.setRating = function(score, challenge, user){
      $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url:'http://groep6api.herokuapp.com/setrating',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        transformRequest: function(obj) {
          var str = [];
          for(var p in obj)
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
          return str.join("&");
        },
        data : {user: user, challenge: challenge, score: score}
      }).success(function (result) {

      }).error(function(err){
        console.log(err);
      });
    };

    challengeFactory.getScore = function(user, challenge){
      return{
        getValue: function(callback){
          $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'http://groep6api.herokuapp.com/getscore',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            transformRequest: function(obj) {
              var str = [];
              for(var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
              return str.join("&");
            },
            data : {user: user, challenge: challenge}
          }).then(function (result) {
            callback(result.data);
          });
        }
      }
    };

    return challengeFactory;
  }
]);
```

Comment: is your first service works?

Comment: Yes the first one works

Comment: Did you make sure the services exist before you're referencing them? If they are in different files include the service file first in your html.

Comment: Give us the source for challengeFactory.. and the series of script references in your markup.

Comment: Two things to check 1. the file for the second service is being added to the page, 2. the service file name is being included with the proper case, if you use the wrong case, the file can be rejected on certain types of webservers

Comment: @Kristian i already checked that ... I'm following the same procedure as for the first service.

I have edited the OP with more details.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, now i see what you did

this code will create new module:

```
angular.module('services', [

])
```

if you want to add to the same module you should do:

```
angular.module('services').service(...)
```

you created two modules with the same name and overwrite your module